# how to do a film mix- 5.1  and mono

Tags: film, mixing, 5.1, mono, mix

i would like to know how to do a proper **film mix** -both **mono** and **5.1** in details.

what are the steps one should follow? is it necessary to EQ all dialogue tracks, foley and fx tracks? if so, why? also if one should always use compressors on the dialouge tracks..should one put the ambience track in center speaker or surround in case of 5.1 mix.

It would also be of great help if someone can provide me some links on this topic..-

Comment: Good luck - it takes most people 10-25 years to learn all the possible answers to what you ask in your questions... and most of those answers will start with "it depends...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're asking here is basically like asking how to build a car from scratch, in detail. Not only is it extremely technical, different cars demand different ways to be built. Same goes here.

A good book to read how 5.1 works and why is Tomlinson Holmans - 5.1 Up And Running.

The only true rule is: You do what you must. Nothing more, nothing less. What one want to accomplish differs totally from person to person, but no matter what your goal is you must always avoid doing neighter anything that doesn't really add to the experience nor neglect something important as far as possible. That's a hard line to stay on and is dependent on experience and judgment, it doesn't matter whether the choice is maximalistic or minimalistic, both the absence of important sounds and excess of things that doesn't belong equally kills the illusion of reality.

Comment: This answer has been tagged AWESOME.

Answer (score 3):

This question is way too broad. there are pleny of places you can read up on personal techniques and mixing preferences on the web. I say this to help you...this kind of question is a bad way to approach people who can share knowledge with you. **Take the time to educate yourself and develop informed...and specific...questions.**

You'll develop some of your own ideas in the process that you can discuss with working professional. it will help you in the long run, and you're more likely to get the responses you're looking for than with the type of question you posted. Here are a few sites to get you going:

- [DesigningSound.org](http://designingsound.org)
- [Soundworks Collection](http://soundworkscollection.com/)
- [FilmSound.org](http://www.filmsound.org/)

Comment: This answer has been tagged AWESOME.

Comment: Thanks Shaun Farley.. I regularly follow the above sites that you have mentioned and i must admit that they are of great help for  students like me. recently we started having practical classes on 5.1 mixing..but we havent been given any input on how to go about it exactly..though some basic guidelines were mentioned..so i was wondering if there are any proper steps that one should follow..

